# ".JPG" or ".jpg"?

Tags: performance, progressive-enhancement

Do someone know the real difference between this two types of files?
I know that i can't link **.JPG** as **.jpg** and vice versa, but there is no proper answer why something like this exists. I also recognized, that **.JPG files are a little bit smaller than .jpg**. Is it a bug or saving "photo.JPG" is better than "photo.jpg"? 
*//I swap the file names to know, that nomenclature is not a problem here. Difference between this pictures is only enhancement.*

[image: screen 1]
[image: screen 2]

**Two forums, which had also this question, but no acceptable answers:**
1.https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070109235224AAQpacy
2.https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1372695

Comment: They are the same type of file. In fact the real extension would be `jpeg`. The three letter `jpg` exists due to backward compatibility with ancient OSes that required extension to have 3 characters at most.

Comment: If it is the same, why .JPG files are smaller than .jpg? I don't think your answer is complete ;)

Comment: I bet 1000$ that the files are **not** the same. Take the `.JPG` file and rename it to `.jpg`... you will see that either it has the same size or Windows is a giant pile of crap.

Comment: I did this with pictures shown on screenshots and the size was different. That's why i asked a question. If you still don't belive me - try it on your own ;) #I changed file enhancement by Photoshop if it is changing anything

Comment: The old time, DOS, had file extension of 3 letters, capitals. Old JPEG images may be of that type, maybe having file names of at most 8 lettters. Unix at that time already had `.jpeg`. Windows followed with `.jpg`. And the files being smaller for .JPG probably is due to the time when memory was costly. The resolution or quality being lower.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for questions and answers regarding *the process of writing software*. Questions that aren't about software development or tools that are primarily used for software development are very much off-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference. Filename extensions do not define the contents of a file or how they "perform" - the file contents do that. Or sometimes the file's mime-type, if that metadata is stored with the file and the OS/applications know to look for it.

The size difference is merely because of a slightly different algorithm, configuration settings, or decisions that the JPEG encoder made at the time the file was saved. Because JPEG is a lossy file format, it's possible to get different file sizes each time the file is saved.

Because Windows uses case-insensitive (by default) but case-preserving filesystems, the capitalization of the filename means nothing. All it says is that the user who saved the file, or the program that they used to save it, chose to use JPG in one case and jpg in another.

As Bakuriu correctly points out, the extension is 3 characters for historical/legacy reasons - there's no reason on modern systems that it needs to be JPG or jpg - it could be JPEG, JPEG or even JPEG-2000 and be equally valid as long as the system/application looking at the file knows how to look at the file header and properly identify it as a JPEG image. Using file extensions to indicate file types is kind of an antiquated notion.

Comment: Thanks for comperhensive answer, that is what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

The file extension is meaningless BUT usually:

- It gives a hint of the expected mime-type of the file
- It determines how the file will be handled by the operating system

It has no effect on the actual mime type of the file and is just convention in naming. The difference however is that NTFS is a case sensitive file system (although turned off by default and only acts in a case preserving way as pointed out by alroc), so accessing it can be problematic in a few circumstances.

---

To actually compare the file on a binary level to determine if there is any difference I suggest using something like [Duplicate files finder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/doubles/) or any other software that creates a cryptographic hash, which you can compare.

Comment: Thanks for useful link, didn't know the picture files are so sensitive :)

Comment: The files are probably different because they vary in actual size rather than size on disk. Hope that helps!

Comment: NTFS case sensitivity is turned off by default, though it is always case-*preserving*.

Comment: @alroc Thanks, updated the post!